# Is throwing exceptions in Scala considered a side-effect?

Tags: scala

Having the code below:

```
val prices = cars map (car => {
  val price = car.getPrice
  Logger.info(s"Car price is $price")
  price
})
```

Is using parentheses fine in the above case or there is a strict imperial to use curly braces like below:

```
val prices = cars map { car => {
  val price = car.getPrice
  Logger.info(s"Car price is $price")
  price
}}
```

I do not like two curly braces and prefer `({ ... })` style, but was warned by another developer that the inside function is side-effecting (logging message) and is 3 lines of code so it must be used with two curly braces and that the whole Scala community uses double curly braces in these cases.

I googled scala code and found [this one](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala):

```
def failed: Future[Throwable] =
  transform({
    case Failure(t) => Success(t)
    case Success(v) => Failure(new NoSuchElementException("Future.failed not completed with a throwable."))
  })(internalExecutor)
```

It has multiple lines but no side effects and my nice notation `({...})` is used here. Should it be changed when the code contains side-effects? Personally I do not like that even if the whole community says "Yes, use double curly braces!" :)

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case I would actually only use curly braces and no parens:

```
val prices = cars map { car =>
  val price = car.getPrice
  Logger.info(s"Car price is $price")
  price
}
```

The example you posted from the scala code is only using parentheses out of necessity, since `transform` is actually a function with multiple argument lists (i.e. `transform(args1)(arg2)`).

I have not heard of any convention relating side-effecting code to a particular choice of block delimiter (`()` vs `{}`), but I do find I prefer the look of `{}` when there are multiple lines in that block.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard about that you should curly braces when there is a side effect in a block of code. Use () for a single statement, and {} for multiple statements. What you call nice notation `({...})` is perfectly fine.